# How Can I add both MX, CNAME Record for Godaddy and GSuite in same cpanel

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting, cname, google-workspace, mx-record

I purchased 10 Business emails from Godaddy as per the request of my client for his employees, He is already using a business email of google G Suite for His personal use. But when we trying to set up CNAME, and MX Records for Godaddy, then Incoming of Google mail service becomes stopped. My Client will not interested to migrate his mail id to Godaddy. Because that is very important to him.

Godaddy's technical team saying, which is not possible to use two email services together. I already purchased 10 Emails But currently which are useless now.

Is any other soluition for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

MX records inform other servers on the internet where to send emails for that domain. You cannot send to multiple hosts with multiple MX record only prioritise mail servers so that if the highest priority does not respond to the sender mail, the next in the list can be tried.

If you want to split mail across different services e.g. GoDaddy and Google then this needs to be configured within the service where email is being directed to, either by using routing rules, aliasing or forwarders. In most instances it is possible to receive and forward a copy to another account.

If you have some users on GoDaddy and some users on Google and they're both on the same email domain then it is possible to configure split delivery. If Google is the primary mail receiver for the domain and a recipient does not exist, routing rules can be configured to route undelivered email on to GoDaddy mail servers.

Comment: Thank you TechNut371 problem fixed :)